# stats command don't return expected value when using ranges

Tags: gnuplot

I'm have some weird behavior with `stats` command when using ranges.
Consider the follow simple example.

```c
$Data<<EOD
 1    10
 2    20
 3    30
 4    40
 5    50
 6    60
 7    70
 8    80
 9    90
10   100
EOD

stats [1:5] $Data u 1   nooutput 
print STATS_records # Result: 10; Expected: 5

stats [1:5] $Data u 1:2 nooutput
print STATS_records # It works fine
```

Why the first `stats` command don't return expected value?
This affects all `stats` results. Is it a bug? Am I missing something? I'm using `version 5.2 patchlevel 8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt to explain this behavior:

If you do

```
stats [1:5] $Data u 1:2 nooutput
```

Column `1` corresponds to `x` and column `2` corresponds to `y`.
With `[1:5]` you limit `x` from 1 to 5, hence 5 records.

If you do

```
stats [1:5] $Data u 1 nooutput
```

Column `1` is "kind of" `y` and the pseudocolumn `0` is "kind of" `x`,
however, you are limiting `x` but not the pseudocolumn `0`, hence 10 records.

So, if you do

```
stats [1:5] $Data u 1:1 nooutput
```

you will get the expected results and the expected statistics on column `1`.

To have a look at all the `STATS` values type `show var STATS`.

But I'm just guessing... I'm sure @Ethan can tell.